# Freeze on localisation fixed but focus needs to be removed from and returned to form

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

I'm trying to localize my app. I originally wrote it in English, with (standard) or (default) localization (my Visual Studio is in German, so I'm not sure what it's called in English).

Visual studio default localization seems to be `en-US`, and I used `de` to write the whole thing in German again.

I have two buttons for language changing, both with a click event. The eventhandlers look like this:

```
private void EnglishButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
     if(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture != CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
        this.Controls.Clear();
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.OpenForms[0].Activate();
        this.Activate();
    }
}
```

For `de` I did the same, just with `de` instead of `en-US`.

This works fine, freeze is fixed. There's one thing I don't like, however: As you can see above, I need to remove focus from the window and return focus to it, else I cannot interact with the window after switching the language.

For me personally this is fine, but I'm worried this might cause an annoying flicker for sighted people. What do you think? Is this OK the way it is now? Or is there a better way?

Comment: For english try "US"

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in changing the localization? Comment the lines `this.Controls.Clear(); InitializeComponent();` and if it is still happening. BTW remove the simicolon after the if clause and put a parenthesis there

Comment: Sorry. The semicolon plus was me typing it manually ^^